# Using code in Trello Cards

Tags: trello, formatting

In Markdown, you should be able to specify a block of code that will not trim whitespace by using four spaces in front of every line of code. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 4):

It does work, you are mostly likely placing a block after a list. Consider separating it with a header

```
---
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
^ Four spaces
```

Will turn into this in your card

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
```

Comment: A blank line will also do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Code blocks can be placed in comments too. Surround the block with three backticks.

````
```
# All your bases are belong to us.
```
````

If you'd like to pre-format just a word or function name, surround it with one backtick.

```
`preformatted`
```

Comment: That helped! +1

Comment: Some comments on formatting from the source: http://help.trello.com/article/821-using-markdown-in-trello